# Coldfusion LDAP Authentication issue / domain prefix

Tags: authentication, coldfusion, ldap, ldap-query

I am currently setting up a dev environment which is an exact copy of our prod environment. The problem is when I try to authenticate a user by using CFLDAP tag in the dev environment, it won't let me authenticate the user without prefixing the username with the domain name while in the prod environment we don't have to prefix the username with the domain name.  See example code below:

Details:

- Windows 2000 Web Server
- ColdFusion 5
- Authenticating to a Windows 2003 Active Directory environment

> Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the server located in the same domain or are they in different domains within the forest?

Comment: The server isn't in a domain.  The prod web server isn't in a domain either.

Comment: If it isn't in the Active Directory domain, how does it have permission to authenticate to the Active Directory? (or is it authenticating against it's local user directory?)

Comment: It isn't authenticating against a local user directory.  Truthfully, I have never used Coldfusion before, I am just trying to get the site working in the dev environment.  Basically, we are running the prod server on a virtual machine, took that image, duplicated it, and put it on a dev virtual machine.  I then changed the AD info so that it would point to the dev AD and no worky :(

Comment: So, are you saying it DOES work if you prefix the username with the domain name?

Answer (score 1):

I have found when using CFLDAP, that using NT style logins for the username will inevitably cause problems and inconsistencies. You are really much better off using the distinguishedName  attribute (DN) for a given user:

```
CN=User,OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com
```

Of course your DN will likely be different - but hopefully that illustrates the point.

Comment: But, this doesn't help to explain why it works in production and not in dev.  

Thanks for the info though.

Comment: I have never been able to reliably pin down the issues I have experienced. The only thing I can confirm is that I periodically get issues when using NT style credentials, and I have never had problems using the user DN to login.